# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: python, django, rss

The following is my Django 1.10 views.py code which produces my blog RSS feed.  I am now trying to add my usage statistics tracking to this.

I am keeping all my statistics code in a designated area of my project.  All I need are these 3 lines of code within the rss **views.py**.  This works in my other views.py, just not in the rss one I am presently suck on.

```
from statistics.service.add import ServiceAdd as ServiceStatisticsAdd
rss_reference = {'utc': timezone.now()}
ServiceStatisticsAdd(request).add('rss', rss_reference, kwargs)
```

The error I am getting is all about **request**.  Originally the database def was **def items(self):**.  When I went to add tracking I expected including **request** would have fixed the error.

This is my **views.py**

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone

from database.ron_home.models import BlogWebsite
from statistics.service.add import ServiceAdd as ServiceStatisticsAdd


class BlogRssFeed(Feed):
    title = "Rons-Home.net Blog RSS Feed"
    link = "/en/blog/"
    description = "Ron Piggott shares updates from his health care and logistics of daily living with a physical disability."

    def item_title(self, obj):
        return obj.entry_title

    def item_description(self, obj):
        return obj.entry

    def item_link(self, obj):
        return reverse('blog:entry', args=[obj.reference])

    def items(self, request, **kwargs):
        rss_reference = {'utc': timezone.now()}
        ServiceStatisticsAdd(request).add('rss', rss_reference, kwargs)
        return BlogWebsite.objects.filter(entry_date__lt=datetime.utcnow()).order_by('-entry_date')[:15]
```

This is the complete **traceback**

```
[09/Apr/2017 14:02:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1430: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField BlogWebsite.entry_date received a naive datetime (2017-04-09 14:02:48) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1430: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField NewsletterEditions.issue_date received a naive datetime (2017-04-09 14:02:48) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1430: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField VideoProfile.date_created received a naive datetime (2017-04-09 14:02:48) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
[09/Apr/2017 14:02:48] "GET /en/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20414
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1430: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField BlogWebsite.entry_date received a naive datetime (2017-04-09 14:02:51.335566) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
[09/Apr/2017 14:02:51] "GET /en/blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21780
Internal Server Error: /en/rss/blog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/syndication/views.py", line 41, in __call__
    feedgen = self.get_feed(obj, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/syndication/views.py", line 169, in get_feed
    for item in self._get_dynamic_attr('items', obj):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/syndication/views.py", line 92, in _get_dynamic_attr
    return attr(obj)
  File "/home/rpiggott/PyCharmProjects/rons-home.net/rss/views.py", line 27, in items
    ServiceStatisticsAdd(request).add('rss', rss_reference, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/rpiggott/PyCharmProjects/rons-home.net/statistics/service/add.py", line 25, in add
    ip_address = get_real_ip(self.request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipware/ip.py", line 36, in get_real_ip
    return get_ip(request, real_ip_only=True, right_most_proxy=right_most_proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipware/ip.py", line 14, in get_ip
    value = request.META.get(key, request.META.get(key.replace('_', '-'), '')).strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'META'
[09/Apr/2017 14:02:54] "GET /en/rss/blog HTTP/1.1" 500 114831
```

Comment: where's your `ServiceStatisticsAdd` function? did you pass in request correctly?

Comment: @Bobby I copied these 3 lines of code from other views.py .  They are correct.  The actual ServiceStatisticsAdd is in the 'statistics' sub-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bit tricky. Add this method to `BlogRssFeed`

```
def get_feed(self, obj, request):
    self.custom_var = request
    return super().get_feed(obj, request)
```

Then

```
ServiceStatisticsAdd(self.custom_var).add('rss', rss_reference, kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks a million.  I really appreciate it.